# searching for a number(eg. mobile number) in more than 1000 gzip files?

Tags: grep, aix, gunzip

I have more than 1500 gzip files and now I have to search for a particular number (eg.mobile number) in those 1500 gzip files. Which command or script should I use to get these problem solved?

Comment: Please check with `zgrep -H "99999" *.gz`

Comment: @binarysta : thank you for suggestions. Some changes has been made by my friend and we have 1500 .dat files and now I have to search for particular number in that .dat files.

Comment: what is the output `file filename.dat`. if the files are just text files you can use `grep -H "99999" *.dat` and if they are still archived the previous should work with `*.dat`

Comment: Also, according to [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583041/searching-for-a-numbereg-mobile-number-in-more-than-1000-gzip-files#comment1085584_583041), you may not in fact have compressed files at all. Please update your question with the actual situation.

Comment: @Kusalananda : my issue is resolved now and i am using AIX server. thanks for suggestions.

Comment: if you can write c code, using `# include <zlib.h>` with `gzopen` to open a zipped file, and prior to that use `popen` to know what each filename is to use gzopen on.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the file types first and then you can search by `grep` or `zgrep`

```
$ file logs.gz 
logs.gz: gzip compressed data

$ zgrep -H "999999999" *.gz
```

For ascii text

```
$ file logs.dat
logs.dat: ASCII text

$ grep -H "999999999" *.dat
```

Comment: A standard installation of AIX (see question tags) does not seem to have the `zgrep` command.

Answer (score 0):

Change `/path/to/gz-files` and `mobilenumber` with actual values.

```
cd /path/to/gz-files
for file in *; do
  printf 'Scanning %s\n' "$file"
  zcat "$file" | grep mobilenumber
done
```